# show selected checkbox in drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have check box and drop down code as below.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="conditions" value="Sample1">Sample 1 
<input type="checkbox" name="conditions" value="Sample2">Sample 2 <br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="conditions" value="Sample3"> Sample 3 
<input type="checkbox" name="conditions" value="Sample4"> Sample 4

<select name="Control">
  <option value="Sample1">Sample 1</option>
  <option value="Sample2">Sample 2</option>
  <option value="Sample3">Sample 3</option>
  <option value="Sample4">Sample 4</option>
</select>
```

Currently I am displaying all the options from check box in the drop down. I want desplay only selected check box in the drop down. Can any one help ??

thank you.

Comment: can you send me the code you tried. Its easy i think.

Comment: sorry, But I don't know anything about javascript :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var $conds = $('input[name="conditions"]'),
    $ctrl = $('select[name="Control"]');
$conds.change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('<option />', {
            value: this.value,
            text: this.nextSibling.nodeValue
        }).appendTo($ctrl)
    } else {
        $ctrl.find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').remove();
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4ma4c/)

Note: The order of checkboxes are not maintained in the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"][name="conditions"]').change(function(){
         if($(this).is(':checked'))
          $('select[name="Control"]').append('<option value="'+$(this).val()+'">'+$(this).val()+'</option>');  
         else
          $('select[name="Control"]').find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').remove();
        });
```

you can try this too.